# Sum of filesize of a list of files

Tags: bash, files, awk

I have a text-file that contains a list of filenames (one filename per line).

Now I would like to calculate the size of all these files. I think I will have to do a `ls -la` on every line of the file and then accumulate the filesize.

I think that `awk` will be part of the solution, but thats just guess.

Answer (score 11):

With GNU `stat`:

```
stat -c %s -- $(<list) | paste -d+ -s - | bc
```

- `stat` displays information about the file

  - `-c` specifies the format, `%s` gives the filesize in bytes
- `paste -d+ -s` concats the output together line by line with a `+` as delimiter
- `bc` piped to `bc`, it will be calculated together.

Add a `-L` option to `stat`, if for symlinks, you'd rather count the size of the file that the symlink eventually resolves to.

That assumes a shell like `ksh`, `bash` or `zsh` with the `$(<file)` operator to invoke split+glob on the content of a file.

Here `list` is expected to be a space, tab or newline (assuming the default value of `$IFS`) delimited list of file patterns (as in `*.txt /bin/*`). For a list of file paths, one per line, you'd need to disable globbing and limit `$IFS` to newline only, or with GNU `xargs`:

```
xargs -rd '\n' -a list stat -c %s -- | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

Comment: Nice... One may have to handle spaces in filenames using something like

  $ find . -type f -exec stat -c %s {} \; | paste -s -d+ | bc

Answer (score 11):

You need just last line of `du -c` output

```
du -ch $(<list) | tail -1
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use the [`-s`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) file test and `perl`:

> -s  File has nonzero size (returns size in bytes).

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sum = 0;
while ( my $filename = <> ) {
    chomp ( $filename );
    $sum += -s $filename;
}

print "Sum is $sum bytes\n";
```

(reads filenames either from `STDIN` or from a file specified on command line, e.g. `myscript.pl file_list.txt`)

You could "one liner" this:

```
perl -nle '$sum += -s $_; END { print $sum }'
```

(and either pipe in a 'file name list' or specify a file argument after it as before)

Comment: Nice. One tweak for efficiency for the one-liner: `perl -nle '$sum += -s $_} END { print $sum'` -- that way you don't redefine the END sub for every iteration of the loop. Check both versions with `perl -MO=Deparse -nle ...`×

Comment: Ah yeah. That's kinda cute. I've run into that before, but am wary about it's impact on readability. Then again, this _is_ a perl one liner....

Comment: If you want unreadability: `perl -nlE'$s+=-s$_}END{say$s'`

Comment: @glennjackman: The `END` can completely ignore, `perl -nle '$sum += -s $_}{ print $sum'`

Comment: You can, but they're somewhat obscure tricks which I'd shy away from when giving someone a suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, using ordinary shell commands. Even handles the filename-with-spaces case. Assumes that list of file names is in a file named `fnames`.

```
tr '\n' '\0' < fnames | xargs -0 cat | wc -c
```

`wc` is oddly useful in counting situations. Keep it in mind.

Comment: Nice thinking-outside-the-box.  But: (1) The question doesn't say anything about access.  It goes without saying that the user must have execute permission on the directories containing the files, but this is the only answer that requires read access.  (2) This approach is very expensive if the file(s) are very large.

Comment: @Scott - legitimate criticisms. Thanks for thinking about it, and writing them down.

Answer (score 0):

I also came up with a solution:

```
cat files.txt | while read f; do ls -la $f; done | awk '{s+=$5;} END {print s;}'
```

Comment: This will break if any of your filenames contain newlines or spaces.

Comment: ahh.. just out of curiosity: is there a way to make above onliner work with all possible filenames?

Comment: Difficult, because of the way you're parsing the output of `ls`. By doing so, you'll always be subject to it's formatting. I tend to ignore the filenames with newlines problem, but files with spaces are distressingly common. But quoting filenames and using the `stat` answer as above would probably do the trick.

Comment: @TobiasGassmann did specify in the question that the filenames are "one per line", so the only change required would be to quote the "$f" in the `ls` portion.

Comment: Still will get the wrong field from the `ls` output though, because `awk` is defaulting to whitespace delimiters.

Comment: The rule of thumb is [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- there are utilities like `stat` that are built for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 0):

For filenames with space in my list, I used this (inspired by @Costas's answer):

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
du -ch $(<list) |tail -1
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```