# Total filesize of a huge list of files

Tags: bash, files

This question is very similar to this one:

[Sum of filesize of a list of files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234012/sum-of-filesize-of-a-list-of-files)

In fact, all my attempts are listed on that question.

The difference is that my list has a huge number of files (1M+), and those attempts doesn't seem to work with so many entries.

For the `stat` and `du` I got these errors:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/stat: Argument list too long
-bash: /usr/bin/du: Argument list too long
```

The perl solution seems to work, but it is very slow, and I'm not sure if it will work with the full list or just crash.

Is there any solution that doesn't involve breaking my original file into pieces and then doing the sum of the partial sums?

Comment: I don't see any reason that perl solution would be much slower than the `stat` or `du` methods.

Comment: The reason for it being slow is likely to be that any solution will need to [stat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) over a million files. You are most likely waiting on disk IO.  Unfortunately there's not much that can help.  Though perhaps it could be done in parallel.

Comment: Does that `xargs -rd '\n' -a list stat -c %s -- | paste -sd+ - | bc` approach mentioned there not work for you? (won't be faster than the perl approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out the size of `/some/dir/file` file which is done with the `lstat()` or `stat()` (if you want to resolve symlinks) system calls, the system needs to:

- lookup `/`'s inode, check that you have read and search access to it and get the information as to where the contents of the `/` directory is from there:
- read the contents of `/` and look-up the `some` entry in there (get its inode number).
- like for `/`, look at `/some`'s inode for permission etc.
- repeat for `/some/dir` and for `/some/dir/file`
- retrieve the size attribute in `/some/dir/file`'s inode

If some of the path components are symlinks, they also need to be resolved.

If there are ACLs or other security contexts involved, that will complicate the look-up further. Doing the look-up as `root` would bypass some of that and possibly speed up the process.

So a `stat()` (or any syscall that looks a file up) can be a costly operation, especially if all that data (the inodes and the contents  of directories and security attributes) is not cached in memory and needs to be retrieved from several locations on a hard disk.

Looking up files in large directories that are not indexed can be quite costly as well even when the contents of that directory is cached.

What could help is sort the list of files so that files in the same directories are listed next to each other and maximise the chance of data be cached by the time a particular file is being looked up.

You'll also want to avoid running too many commands, or do unnecessary extra work on top.

So:

```
LC_ALL=C sort file | perl -lne '$s += -s} END {print $s'
```

(as `root`) is likely to be close to the fastest you'll be able to easily achieve.

(here using the `stat()` system call, so that for symlinks, the size of the file they point to be considered).

There are ways to optimise it further. For instance, if you have:

```
/some/very/very/deep/dir/structure/with/many/levels/of/subdirs/file1
/some/very/very/deep/dir/structure/with/many/levels/of/subdirs/file2
/some/very/very/deep/dir/structure/with/many/levels/of/subdirs/file3
/some/very/very/deep/dir/structure/with/many/levels/of/subdirs/file4
```

It would likely be faster to `open()` `/some/very/very/deep/dir/structure/with/many/levels/of/subdirs` once and then do some `fstatat()` for `file1`, `file2`... relative to that directory to avoid having to do the look up of all those dir components each time, but implementing that kind of optimisation would not be trivial (though not that difficult either).

There are some specific optimisations that could be done  as well depending on your data. For instance, if a file is listed more than once, you could optimise out the second and further `stat()`s. If `/foo` is a symlink to `/bar` and the  same thousands of files are listed under `/foo` as they are under `/bar`, then if you can realise they are actually the  same files, you can optimise out some `stat()`s. Same for `/foo/file` vs `/foo/./file`, `/bar/../foo/file`...